# CefSharp Winform deployment via ClickOnce and requirements vc redist in Visual Studio 2019 - Error

Tags: c#, c++, winforms, clickonce, cefsharp

When launch clickonce setup of CefSharp Winform Application return an error installing vc++ 2019 redist (vc++ is in deployment requirements). It's generate an empty directory during install.

"C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD66FC.tmp\vcredist_x86\vcredist_x86.exe has changed since it was initially published."

Both on Windows 7 and 10, same error. I need to install manually package.

I've removed Visual C++ "14" from requirements, but I don't know how include c++ library in the Application code.

Comment: What research did you do before posting here? A quick search and I see lots of other reports of this error,  most likely based on the limited information provided is https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/570552/publish-prerequisite-visual-c-14-has-changed-since.html

Comment: Hi @amaitland. I've googled and reached, but not working for me. Changing link in bootstrapper package (it version) rimain the same problem (vs community 2019 16.3.6). 
I show you the partial install log:

(28/10/2019 17:49:06) Downloading 'vcredist_x86\vc_redist.x86.exe' from 'https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/14.23.27820/VC_Redist.x86.exe' to 'C:\Users\Test\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD6C89.tmp\'

In that directory  ramians (VSD6C89.tmp) only vcredist_x86\, install.txt and setup.exe.
As you can try, link is correct... I'm not understand why not work and I'm searching a work around.

Comment: I've tried to run that setup.exe in the temp directory and it retur same error. If I run, mannually VC_redist.x86.exe (downloaded from the link) it is work...

Comment: Maybe this error? C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5403,5): warning MSB3157: non è stato possibile trovare una corrispondenza con le impostazioni cultura 'it-IT' per l'elemento 'Visual C++ "14" Runtime Libraries (x86)'. Verranno usate le impostazioni cultura 'en'. There is not en package in the directory bootstrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround. I'm using a service, but it should work in a winform:

```
 private void InstallVCredist()
    {
        string exe = @"path to exe\VC_redist.x86.exe"; //set path
        string stp = @"\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"; //set subkey
        using (RegistryKey reg = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(stp)) //recall registry
        {
            if (reg != null)
            {
                foreach (string dname in reg.GetSubKeyNames()) //loop search
                {
                    using (RegistryKey sreg = reg.OpenSubKey(dname))
                    {
                        if (sreg.GetValue("DisplayName").ToString() == "Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable (x86) - 14.23.27820") //set dispayname of version
                        {
                            vcredist = "1"; //it's mine control variable
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (vcredist == "0") //now testing if it was found 
        {
            Process vc = new Process();
            vc.StartInfo.FileName = exe;
            //silent install
            vc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/install /passive /norestart";
            vc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            vc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            //silent install
            vc.Start(); 
            vc.WaitForExit(); //as he says ;)
        }
    }
```